# MailChimp form with single opt-in (API)

Tags: html, api, forms, landing-page, mailchimp

How to easily make MailChimp API form without double opt-in?

Using their API is hard for people with no coding skills and 3rd party tools like POWr or Privy don't have option to disable MailChimp double opt-in.

Comment: Are you having premium version ?

Comment: Nope but I can pay if it gonna help

Comment: No, don't buy it until you know there is no another way. I was just thinking